# Cron Job - Could not open input file:

Tags: ssh, cron, cgi-bin

I have set up a php file to run that just echos hello.

```
<?php
echo hello;
?>
```

My cron job looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f “/home/username/public_html/mls/test.php”
```

when my script runs i get a confirmation email that says:

```
Could not open input file: /home/username/public_html/mls/test.php
```

I don't know what is causing this. I am using godaddy's virtual private server with cpanel x installed.  I have used the ssh to set permissions 777 on folder and file and still can not get it to run.

Any advice would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: `echo hello;` should be `echo "hello"`. Does it matter that you have typographer's quotes in your output? I do hope that you haven't used them in the actual command.

Comment: i meant "hello."  Its not an issue with my php...again my cron isn't even locating the file.

Comment: Try a path that starts just after /home/username/ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason PHP cannot open the file. Try replacing /usr/local/bin/php -f with "ls -la" to try to crib some more information. Remember to NOT quote the file name in the crontab: php -f filename.php, not php -f "filename.php", unless it contains spaces -- and then it's better to use single quotes.

Possibly, try "ls -la /home", "ls -la /home/username", "ls -la ~/public_html" and so on.

Also try appending

```
2>&1
```

to the command line, in case only stdout is mailed to you (I don't really think so, but being sure costs little).

## One other possibility

The crontab as it is refers `/home/username/public_html/mls/test.php` - that is, a public HTML directory inside *username*'s commonest value for a home directory.

It is possible that the cron job is either not running with the appropriate user and privileges, or that the user it "sees" is actually a **virtual** user - there *is* no "/home/username" at all - and the "home directory" is elsewhere, possibly even existing just as long as the cron job runs. In this case the solution *might* be to refer to

```
~/public_html/mls/test.php
```

or, as described above, to first run a command such as `pwd` or `ls -la` to determine exactly where the cron job's current working directory *is*.

If this, too, fails, then another workaround could be to invoke the PHP HTTP handler via curl or lynx:

```
/usr/bin/curl http://www.thishostname.com/mls/test.php
```

Possibly using either some environment variable or curl header or _GET option to authenticate to the script as the cron job, and avoid it being accessible from the outside.

Comment: Thanks, i just needed to remove the "" around the url path.  Now it works fine.  Thank you.

Comment: First time to set up my cron job using GoDaddy Cpanel and `/usr/bin/curl` worked out! Thanks!